# How do I build a function out of list of tuples?

Tags: haskell

I want to convert this list of tuples:

```
[(1,'a'),(2,'b') ... ]
```

into a function that could be written as this:

```
g :: Int -> Char
g 1 = 'a'
g 2 = 'b'
 .
 .
 .
```

Use case:

```
g 1  -- | 'a'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The signature of such a function would be `[(a, b)] -> a -> b`. It sounds like a common operation, so [let's search on Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5B%28a%2C%20b%29%5D%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20b) to see if it already exists. Oh, it almost does, and it's called [`lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3alookup):

> ```
> lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
> ```
>
> `lookup key assocs` looks up a key in an association list.

What we need to do is flip the first two arguments (use `flip`) and strip the `Maybe` off the result (compose with `fromJust`). Result:

```
g :: Int -> Char
g = fromJust . flip lookup [(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')]
```

Comment: Oh didn't think of it as a lookup problem haha. What about tuples of arbitrary length, where the first (n-1) elements are arguments mapping to the last element, like g :: Int -> Int -> Char

Comment: @chibro2: Change your table to be of the form `[((arg1,arg2,...), value)]` instead. Then you can still use `lookup`.

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to use `fromMaybe (error "msg")` with a good message instead of `fromJust`. That way it's easier to find the bug if you end up calling the function where it's not defined.